How can one deduce the inversion formula from Katznelson's theorem 1.11 in his chapter VI Fourier Transform on the line under his assumption only
My question is about Y. Katznelson's book Introduction to Harmonic Analysis, chapter VI concerning the Fourier transform on the real line. (In what follows $L^1$ is meant for functions on the line.) Theorem 1.11 states that for $f \in L^1$ we have in the $L^1$-norm: $$f = \lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda}\left(1-\frac{|\xi|}{\lambda}\right)\hat f(\xi)e^{i\xi x} d\xi.$$ The author then says that when $\hat f \in L^1$ (in fact I don't see here the hat over $f$ in my e-book copy of K.'s book, but it's clear to me that this is what he means) then the integral in the above formula converges uniformly in $x$ to $\int\hat f(\xi)e^{i\xi x} d\xi.$ (From this he deduces the inversion formula saying that this last integral divided by $2\pi$ equals $f(x)$ a.e. - together with other properties, but a priori this part doesn't seem to me to make problem.) My question is: how can I prove the asserted convergence of the integral (uniformly on $x$ makes no extra difficulty because in majorations $x$ disappears, $|e^z|$ being $1$ for $z$ purely imaginary.) To me it seems that $\hat f \in L^1$ is not sufficient, the function $\xi \hat f(\xi)$ needing to be integrable too. How does one argue without this extra assumption?
Supplement: the title may let some readers think that a proof of the inversion formula is discussed here, and be disappointed because to finish such a proof something non trivial has to be added to the answer to my question. Now there is a result that can be used for this: when a Cauchy sequence $(g_n)$ of $L^p$-functions ($1 <= p < \infty$) converges almost everywhere to a function $g$, then $g \in L^p$ and the sequencce converges in $L^p$ to $g$. (This can be found -  with proof - in Bourbaki's Integration in the § introducing $L^p$.) Unicity of limits in the Hausdorff space $L^p$ of classes of equivalent functions (equivalent meaning equal a.e.) yields the desired conclusion. Surprisingly the uniform convergence in my question above is not used, so may-be Katznelson had another argument in mind.

If $\widehat{f}\in L^1$ then
$${1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \widehat{f}(\xi)e^{ix\xi }\,d\xi -{1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{-\lambda}^\lambda \left (1-{|\xi|\over \lambda} \right)\widehat{f}(\xi)e^{ix\xi }\,d\xi\\ ={1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{|\xi|\ge \lambda} \widehat{f}(\xi)e^{ix\xi}\,d\xi +{1\over 2\pi\lambda}\int\limits_{-\lambda}^\lambda |\xi|\widehat{f}(\xi)e^{ix\xi}\,d\xi $$
Thus $$\left |{1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \widehat{f}(\xi)e^{ix\xi }\,d\xi -{1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{-\lambda}^\lambda \left (1-{|\xi|\over \lambda} \right)\widehat{f}(\xi)e^{ix \xi }\,d\xi\right |\\
\le {1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{|\xi|\ge \lambda} |\widehat{f}(\xi)|\,d\xi+{1\over 2\pi\lambda}\int\limits_{-\lambda}^\lambda |\xi||\widehat{f}(\xi)|\,d\xi $$
The first term tends to $0$ when $\lambda\to \infty.$
Concerning the second term for fixed $\lambda_0>0$ and $\lambda>\lambda_0$ we have
$${1\over \lambda}\int\limits_{-\lambda}^\lambda |\xi||\widehat{f}(\xi)|\,d\xi={1\over \lambda}\int\limits_{-\lambda_0}^{\lambda_0} |\xi||\widehat{f}(\xi)|\,d\xi+{1\over \lambda}\int\limits_{\lambda_0\le |\xi|\le \lambda} |\xi||\widehat{f}(\xi)|\,d\xi\\
\le {\lambda_0\over\lambda}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty|\widehat{f}(\xi)|\,d\xi+\int\limits_{|\xi|\ge \lambda_0}|\widehat{f}(\xi)|\,d\xi $$ For fixed $\varepsilon>0$ there is   $\lambda_0>0$ so that
the second term is less than ${1\over 2}\varepsilon.$ Next there is $\lambda_1>\lambda_0$ so that
$${\lambda_0\over\lambda_1}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty|\widehat{f}(\xi)|\,d\xi<{1\over 2}\varepsilon $$
Then
$${1\over \lambda}\int\limits_{-\lambda}^\lambda |\xi||\widehat{f}(\xi)|\,d\xi< \varepsilon,\quad \lambda>\lambda_1$$
Another proof can be the following. We have $${1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{-\lambda}^\lambda \left (1-{|\xi|\over \lambda} \right)\widehat{f}(\xi)e^{i\xi x}\,d\xi \\ = {1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty }^\infty  \left (1-{|\xi|\over \lambda} \right)_+\widehat{f}(\xi)e^{i\xi x}\,d\xi$$ (+ stands for positive part)
Thus
$$\left |{1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\widehat{f}(\xi)e^{i\xi x}\,d\xi-{1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{-\lambda}^\lambda \left (1-{|\xi|\over \lambda} \right)\widehat{f}(\xi)e^{i\xi x}\,d\xi\right |\\
\le {1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\left [1- \left(1-{|\xi|\over \lambda} \right)_+\right ]|\widehat{f}(\xi)| \,d\xi
$$
The absolute values of the integrated functions are bounded by the integrable function $|\widehat{f}(\xi)|$ and convergent pointwise to $0,$ when $\lambda\to\infty.$ Therefore by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem the limit of the last integral is $0.$ As the last integral is independent of $x$ the convergence of the first expression to $0$ is  uniform with respect to $x.$

Thanks. I need some time to verify your argument. A priori it looks good. For your remark: I tried things with integration by parts, similar to what you suggest (or even identical). To my surprise, it didn't help. My problem = what I had to show going to zero I could only prove bounded showed up again

I have omitted the application of the Lebesgue dominated theorem. Now the proof is elementary, hopefully correct.

I verified your original proof and found it correct. I don't know why you replaced it. I'll have to verify your new proof, which is more on the line of what I tried (may-be a more natural way of doing). A little correction: In your (new) equality at the beginning, the factor $\xi$ in the second integral of the right-hand side should be taken in absolute value, of course. But that doesn't affect what followss.

Yes, this new proof of yours I find correct, except for the little correction I mention in my last comment. I finally understand your replacement: to make things 'elementary' (first I did not understand omitted the application of the L. d. th.: "omitted" seemed to say there is now something missing, whils you in fact meant avoided the use of that theorem)

BUT imho Lebesgue integral theory isn't any way quite 'elementary' and any one who has studied it really - i.e. up to the point where this study makes sense (for those who have had before a more elementary integral e.g. Riemann's) - must have encountered the dominated convergence theorem as well as probably the completeness of L^p for 1 <= p < +oo: these are the 'heart' of the gain brought by Lebesgue integration ... to which one should add Fubini's th. for which I never saw a Riemann analogue stated clearly much less proven)

Thanks. Absolute value corrected. In the proof of convergence no advanced tools (no Fubini, completness etc). The integrated functions are continuous.

OK but I think we should restore your first proof, some might prefer it. I think two answers to one Q. from the same person should be possible (I don't see why not). In case there is no better solution: I printed that proof (in its version without the remark) - to study it without having my PC on all the time - I could scan the print to recreate an answer with it (sending the picture to you so that it shows you as author)

I have added the proof based on the Lebesgue theorem.

Very good. This is even simpler than your original argument!

Except that it is no more obvious that the limit is uniform with respect to $x$. (This is no problem with your original version, nor with your new 'elementary' proof.) Does this matter? For a complete answer to my question, yes. For the continuation (getting the inversion formula) may-be; the fact that it is mentioned in the book lets me think that it is at least helpful.

Now my question in the body of my original input differs from its title. It would have been much too complicated to put into the title something corresponding more precisely to that question. And much less attractive. As it is, I feel I never got so many views in such a short time to a Q. in this math' site. Some may have hoped to see a discussion of the proof of the inv. formula here, and be disppointed if it doesn't happen. I thought that this continuation should be easy. Now that I am confronting it, I suspect that it might be less trivial. Because the real line isn't compact ...

OK. Actually the uniform convergence followed, as the function $|\widehat{f}(\xi)|$ is indepenent of $x.$ I have again modified the last part to make it clear.

The continuation looks like this. We have functions f_r (r for lambda) which have for r->oo a limit for uniform convergence (a function described by an integral like the Fourier transform up to a +/- sign) and another one in L^1 which is $f$. Uniqueness of limits in Hausdorff spaces would show that the two limits are the same up to equivalence (equality a.e.) but here we have 2 different topologies none of which is finer than the other. (They can both be defined on all complex functions on |R in a natural way, norm top. on L^1 is convergence in the mean.) But all f_r are in L^1 -> what then?

R.Szwarc: I don't see your last edit. What happened?

I can see it. The last expression is small when $\lambda$ is large. That's why the first difference where $x$ is still present is small for large $\lambda$ independtly of $x.$ This what uniform convergence means. We have to stop the discussion as it is gettin too long for MathExch standards.

Yes we can stop here. Apparently a new comment entered is made visible to others without the page being re-displayed. By clicking on the reload button I see now your last edit. Thanks
